# Drop-down list that stays upon click without JS

Tags: css

I want to make my drop down menu stay when user clicks on element. Currently, it displays when user **hover** over element, like this:

```
div.nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: list-item;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I can change `hover` selector to `active` but that will not make the drop-down list stay upon click (releasing click will hide it).

My question is, **is it possible to have the drop down stay upon click without javascript?**

Comment: Not really. You'd have to add a `active` class with javascript in order for you navigation to stay open.

Comment: So this is completely impossible without JS?

Comment: Completely impossible....no, but there are **"hacks"** that work. Try googling "checkbox hack". Frankly, i wouldn't bother, it's a lot less hassle to just use Jquery.

Comment: @Paulie_D Of course, but I am aiming to cater for users who have JS disabled.

Comment: You would know your audience of course, but the % of users who actually run with JS disabled is miniscule.

Comment: @Paulie_D According to my stats, they are more than the average site for certain, which is why I am hoping to find a solution. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly possible- you can determine visibility of a sibling list from the checked state of a hidden input:

### Option 1, `:checked`

```css
li,
input:checked + ul {
  display: block
}
ul ul,
input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="menuTrigger">Item</label>
    <input id="menuTrigger" type="checkbox" />
    <ul>
      <li>Sub item</li>
      <li>Sub item</li>
      <li>Sub item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### Option 2, `:target`

Or alternatively, using the `:target` pseudo, although depending on your architecture, this may not place nicely with route configuration. Additionally, the list cannot be toggled once shown (except if an alternate `:target` is initiated).

```css
li,
ul:target {
  display: block
}
ul ul,
input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#show">Item</a>
    <ul id="show">
      <li>Sub item</li>
      <li>Sub item</li>
      <li>Sub item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah right. Very bizarre. Is it only possible using the checkbox input?

Comment: I've added an alternative approach using `:target`

Comment: I was just thinking of `:target`, wish I could upvote again. :)

Comment: I like the :target approach, can you kindly elaborate on initiating an alternate target to hide the box again?

Comment: `:target` relates effectively relates to the `href` of the clicked link, as such- to change the target path (thereby hiding the list) you would need to either alter directly using JS, or click a link which changes it (has a different href)